# Closed and bounded subsets of $\ell_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am investigating closed and bounded subsets of $\ell_1$ endowed with the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm. For concreteness, $$\ell_1 = \left\{x = (x_1,x_2,\dots)\ |\ \|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i| < \infty\right\}.$$ I am considering the following example.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the sequence $$\tilde{e}_n = (0,\dots,0,1 + 1/n,0,\dots).$$ That is, the $i$-th entry of $\tilde{e}_n$ is $0$ if $i \neq n$ and $1+1/n$ if $i = n$. Then set $A = \{\tilde{e}_1,\tilde{e}_2,\dots\} \subset \ell_1.$ Clearly $A$ is bounded, but is it closed? I believe it is vacuously closed since $A$ does not have any limit points. My end goal here is to exhibit a closed and bounded subset $A$ of $\ell_1$ such that the continuous function $f: \ell_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sum_i x_i$ does not achieve its infimum on $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this set is closed. To see this, note first that $\|x-y\|_1\ge2$ for all $x,y\in A$ with $x\neq y$. If $z\in\ell^1\setminus A$, either $B(z,1)\subset\ell^1\setminus A$ or there exists $x\in A$ such that $\varepsilon:=\|x-z\|_1\le1$. By our previous observation, this implies $B(z,\varepsilon/2)\subset\ell^1\setminus A$. This shows $\ell^1\setminus A$ is open.

This is a good example for what you are trying to prove since $\{f(x):x\in A\}=\{1+\frac1n:n\ge1\}$, which has no minimum.

Comment: Maybe a short proof or argument would be nice, though?

Comment: @ClementC. Added.